# Vendor Bill and BillPayment transaction in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to find out the relation of Vendor Bill and the BillPayment records in NetSuite through the SS2.0. My requirement is to find all the Payment of a Bill. I can understand that this is done using the transaction table/records.

How do I link this both ? I am trying to search my record something like this. But it has both the record billpayment and bill.

```
    var transactionSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "transaction",
    filters: [
       ["name","anyof","375"], 
       "AND", 
       ["trandate","within","8/9/2017","8/13/2017"], 
       "AND", 
       ["creditamount","isnotempty",""]
    ],
    columns: [
       search.createColumn({
          name: "trandate",
          sort: search.Sort.ASC
       }),
       "type",
       "tranid",
       "entity",
       "account",
       "statusref",
       "creditamount",
       "total",
       "externalrefnumber",
       "otherrefnum",
       search.createColumn({
          name: "originator",
          join: "billingTransaction"
       }),
       "applyingtransaction",
       "appliedtotransaction",
       "internalid",
       "externalrefnumber",
       "externalid",
       search.createColumn({
          name: "appliedtotransaction",
          join: "applyingTransaction"
       }),
       search.createColumn({
          name: "appliedtotransaction",
          join: "appliedToTransaction"
       }),
       search.createColumn({
          name: "transactionnumber",
          join: "billingTransaction"
       })
    ]
 });
```

Any suggestion is welcome...

Answer (score 2):

If you know the Vendor Bill internal ID then you can get a list of all related Bill Payments for that Vendor Bill by using these search criteria. Please note that this search is specifically pulling in the Bill Payment records, so if you need additional data from the Vendor Bill itself you will need to use the appliedtotransaction record connection. See the columns in the search for better understanding.

```
function vendorPayments(billId) {
    var vendorpaymentSearchObj = search.create({
        type: "vendorpayment",
        filters: [
           ["type","anyof","VendPymt"], 
           "AND", 
           ["appliedtotransaction.internalid","anyof",billId.toString()]
        ],
        columns: [
           "entity",
           "tranid",
           "appliedtolinkamount",
           "appliedtotransaction",
           search.createColumn({
              name: "entity",
              join: "appliedToTransaction"
           }),
           search.createColumn({
              name: "memomain",
              join: "appliedToTransaction"
           }),
           search.createColumn({
              name: "approvalstatus",
              join: "appliedToTransaction"
           })
        ]
    });
    return vendorpaymentSearchObj;
}
```

Comment: Will try this ... I also need some info from the Vendor Bill. 
Can you please let me know how to find all the fields for the "appliedToTransaction" records. The normal record browser does not show any thing ....

Comment: @Arindam You can typically get to those fields by using the join "appliedToTransaction" and then for the name property use the internal id of the Vendor Bill field you are looking for. If you dont know how to lookup the internal id of fields in NetSuite then just hit the help button and search for internal id. You will find that pretty easily.

Comment: I am able to find the details.  Thanks for your help.
My question was how can i find all the available fields for "appliedToTransaction" record which you have done join.